# How to import empty values to csv if not found? [Python, Scrapy, Web Scrapping]

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am writting my first web scrapping project and I want to scrap from booking.com.

I'd like to scrap info about include breakfast in hotel.

The problem is - I want every value to be ["Brekafast included"] or empty value [""] if there is no info about it. If Im runnig my code (below) I only get few values ["Brekafast included"].

I don't know how to solve this, bc when breakfast is not included there is no class "e05969d63d" in property card in this hotel (this class is directed to info about breakfast if it is included)

So if Hotel1 and Hotel3 have "Breakfast included" and Hotel2 doesn't have breakfast included.

I would like to export sth like ["Breakfast included","","Breakfast included"]

But I get only : ["Breakfast included", "Breakfast included"]

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"



import scrapy
import logging
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter


class CsvPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open ('hotel.tmp','wb')
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.file,str)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()
    def close_spider(self,spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()
    def process_items(self,item,spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

```
class hotelsNY(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hotelsNY"
    start_urls =[]
    #start_urls = ['https://www.booking.com/searchresults.pl.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaLYBiAEBmAEeuAEXyAEM2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALX3uicBsACAdICJGRlODkzYmJmLTIyZjQtNDYwNi04YzYwLWIxOWRlMGU0MmM0MdgCBeACAQ&sid=7ab6fb8585341629f1a790546e37a1c5&aid=304142&ss=Nowy+Jork&ssne=Nowy+Jork&ssne_untouched=Nowy+Jork&lang=pl&sb=1&src_elem=sb&src=index&dest_id=20088325&dest_type=city&checkin=2022-12-30&checkout=2023-01-03&group_adults=2&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&sb_travel_purpose=leisure&offset=0']
    for i in range (0, 10):
        start_urls.append('https://www.booking.com/searchresults.pl.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaLYBiAEBmAEeuAEXyAEM2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALX3uicBsACAdICJGRlODkzYmJmLTIyZjQtNDYwNi04YzYwLWIxOWRlMGU0MmM0MdgCBeACAQ&sid=7ab6fb8585341629f1a790546e37a1c5&aid=304142&ss=Nowy+Jork&ssne=Nowy+Jork&ssne_untouched=Nowy+Jork&lang=pl&sb=1&src_elem=sb&src=index&dest_id=20088325&dest_type=city&checkin=2022-12-30&checkout=2023-01-03&group_adults=2&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&sb_travel_purpose=leisure&offset=' + str(i*25))
        
    custom_settings = {
        'LOG_LEVEL': logging.WARNING,
        'FEED_EXPORTERS': {'csv': 'scrapy.exporters.CsvItemExporter'},
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
        'FEED_URI': 'hotels_tmp1.csv'
    }
   

    def parse(self, response):
        nexturl = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.pl.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaLYBiAEBmAEeuAEXyAEM2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALX3uicBsACAdICJGRlODkzYmJmLTIyZjQtNDYwNi04YzYwLWIxOWRlMGU0MmM0MdgCBeACAQ&sid=7ab6fb8585341629f1a790546e37a1c5&aid=304142&ss=Nowy+Jork&ssne=Nowy+Jork&ssne_untouched=Nowy+Jork&lang=pl&sb=1&src_elem=sb&src=index&dest_id=20088325&dest_type=city&checkin=2022-12-30&checkout=2023-01-03&group_adults=2&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&sb_travel_purpose=leisure&offset=0'
        #all_names = response.xpath('//*[@data-testid="title"]')
        alH = response.xpath('//*[@data-testid="property-card"]').getall()
        for name in allH:
            hotelName = response.xpath('//*[@data-testid="title"]/text()').extract(),
            address = response.xpath('//*[@data-testid="address"]/text()').extract(),
            price = response.xpath('//*[@data-testid="price-and-discounted-price"]/text()').extract(),
            dist = response.xpath('//span[@data-testid="distance"]/text()').extract(),
            breakfast = response.xpath('//span[@class="e05969d63d"]/text()').extract(),
            yield {'hotelName': hotelName, 'address': address, 'price': price, 'dist': dist, 'breakfast': breakfast}
```

```
process = CrawlerProcess(
    {
     'USER_AGENT':'Mozilla/4.0 (comatible;MSIE 7.0;Window NT 5.1)'
     })
process.crawl(hotelsNY)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your spider.

1. once you use `getall()` on `allH` xpath, you are extracting the text of that xpath expression and you can no longer use it as a selector for which you can chain.
2. Use relative xpath expressions with the chained selectors so that instead of extracting lists of matching elements, you are iterating through the page row by row which I think was your intention in the first place.
3. To ensure that "breakfast" becomes an empty string you can just test if it is None, and explicitly set it to the empty string if needed.

here is an example:

notice that there is a './/' in the xpath expressions in the for loop. these are relative xpath expressions.  and also notice how I chain the selectors by calling `i.xpath` instead of `response.xpath` inside the for loop.

```
        allH = response.xpath('//*[@data-testid="property-card"]')
        for i in allH:
            hotelName = i.xpath('.//*[@data-testid="title"]//text()').get()
            address = i.xpath('.//*[@data-testid="address"]//text()').get()
            price = i.xpath('.//*[@data-testid="price-and-discounted-price"]//text()').get()
            dist = i.xpath('.//span[@data-testid="distance"]//text()').get()
            breakfast = i.xpath('//span[@class="e05969d63d"]//text()').get()
            if breakfast is None:
                breakfast = ""
            yield {'hotelName': hotelName, 'address': address, 'price': price, 
                  'dist': dist, 'breakfast': breakfast}
```

Comment: Well, thank you!! It works, I see my mistakes, my first scrapping so I hope it will get only better :)

Comment: you did good @jl0506

Answer (score 0):

You are currently not using the `for name in allH` loop at all, also in the line above you define it as `alH` not `allH`. 
I would recommend you import `BeautifulSoup` like this `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` and then change your for loop to the following:

```
for name in alH:
    hotel = BeautifulSoup(name.extract(), features="lxml")
    hotelName = hotel.find(attrs={"data-testid":"title"}).get_text()
    print(hotelName)
    address = hotel.find(attrs={"data-testid":"address"}).get_text()
    price = hotel.find(attrs={"data-testid": "price-and-discounted-price"}).get_text()
    dist = hotel.find(attrs={"data-testid": "distance"}).get_text()
    breakfast = hotel.find(class_="e05969d63d")

    if breakfast:
        breakfast = breakfast.get_text()
    else:
        breakfast = " "
    print(breakfast)
    yield {'hotelName': hotelName, 'address': address, 'price': price, 'dist': dist, 'breakfast': breakfast}
```

Using `BeautifulSoup` you can much more easily pull data from html and xml files and you can use it further up in your code too to replace any `xpath` calls. This is just a quick example of how it can be used but I recommend you look into this tool further.